# After updating to Nova 3.8, ID Field disappeared from Index View

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

we've just updated to Laravel Nova version 3.8, but this caused that the ID fields have disappeared from the indexes (the list views):

```
        ID::make('ID', 'idcontact')->sortable(),
```

It's like that the column is visible, but the actual ID number is not there:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refering to Nova Upgrade Guide:

After updating to a new Nova release, you should be sure to update Nova's JavaScript and CSS assets using `nova:publish` and clear any cached views with `view:clear`. This will ensure the newly-updated Nova version is using the latest versions.

```
php artisan nova:publish
php artisan view:clear
```

Did the trick for me, hope it helps!